# How does the Rage Shield's flame damage bonus work?

Tags: clash-of-heroes

In Might and Magic: Clash of Heroes, the demon faction item, Rage Shield, is described as having the the ff. effect: "flame damage is applied to enemy formations for an additional row".

What attack or which units have attacks that count as flame damage for the purposes of the Rage Shield?

[image: Rage Shield]